# pandas datetimeindex between_time function(how to get a not_between_time)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas df, and I use between_time a and b to clean the data. How do I 
get a non_between_time behavior?

I know i can try something like.

```
df.between_time['00:00:00', a]   
df.between_time[b,23:59:59']
```

then combine it and sort the new df. It's very inefficient and it doesn't work for me as I have data betweeen 23:59:59 and 00:00:00

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the index locations for rows with time between `a` and `b`, and then use `df.index.diff` to remove those from the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
text = '''\
date,time, val
20120105, 080000,   1
20120105, 080030,   2
20120105, 080100,   3
20120105, 080130,   4
20120105, 080200,   5
20120105, 235959.01, 6
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(text), parse_dates=[[0, 1]], index_col=0)
index = df.index
ivals = index.indexer_between_time('8:01:30','8:02')
print(df.reindex(index.diff(index[ivals])))
```

yields

```
                             val
date_time                       
2012-01-05 08:00:00            1
2012-01-05 08:00:30            2
2012-01-05 08:01:00            3
2012-01-05 23:59:59.010000     6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, tried and it works. not very familiar with reindex